# Remove index key from Array for accessing to object?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, class

How do I remove Index key from array?

For example:

```
$getProduct = Product::find($product->ProductID);
```

and the array structure will look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product Object
        (
            [id] => 26552
            [name] => Product Name One
        )

)
```

To get the value of `name`, I have to do this:

```
echo $getProduct[0]->name;
```

I want to get the value like this:

```
echo $getProduct->name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$getProduct = $getProduct[0];
```

will put the first item in the array into it's own variable, from which you can then access

```
$getProduct->name
```

However I would suggest putting it into a variable with a different name for the sake of your code readability, maybe:

```
$product = $getProduct[0];
echo $product->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value as you want, you should change your class "Product" in the way it returns you the object you are initializing after calling the find method.

Comment: Well in the Product class, its fetch like this: `$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Product');`