# Remove Index from array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove index key from Array for accessing to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629520/remove-index-key-from-array-for-accessing-to-object)

I need to be able to access the `term_id` value but I don't know the number or index assossiated with the array. How can I access it?

I would to access it like this `$value->term_id`, right now I need to access it by putting the number after the value (`$value->[26]->term_id`).

```
Array
(
    [26] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 26
            [name] => Night Life.
            [slug] => shopping-and-night-life
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 28
            [taxonomy] => map_categories
            [description] => Most of the late night clubs, bars and pubs in Victoria are situated downtown. Here are a few to check out:
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [object_id] => 925
        )

)
```

Comment: Simple Solution: `$value = $value[26]; echo $value->term_id;` It's because you have an array with an object inside.

Comment: `stdClass` is an _object_, so access with the `->`

Comment: The point is he doesn't know the 26 index///

Comment: This is the correct syntax: $value[26]->term_id. You cannot remove the index, because that wouldn't be an array anymore ...

Comment: I can't get the point. You have an array and every value is an _object_. Why would you wanna get a property of that object without using the array index?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `array_values()` to "reset" the array indices:

```
$new = array_values($old);
```

Would result with

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 26
            [name] => Night Life.
            [slug] => shopping-and-night-life
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 28
            [taxonomy] => map_categories
            [description] => Most of the late night clubs, bars and pubs in Victoria are situated downtown. Here are a few to check out:
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [object_id] => 925
        )

)
```

Regardless of what the previous array index was.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried it by doing  $i = array_keys($cat);and that also worked!

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is an array so you would access it like this: `$value[26]->term_id` if you don't want to have to put the key you would just need to set another variable equal to the object inside the array:

```
$value2 = $value[26];
echo $value2->term_id;
```

If you don't know if the value `26` then use a foreach.

```
foreach($value as $key => $val) {
     $term_id = $val->term_id;
}
```

Of if you know there is only one element in the array you could do this:

```
$value2 = end($value);
$term_id = $value2->term_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either search for it **OR** write an algorithm whereby you do not lose it in the first place.